# Advancing internal row pointer after every page refresh

Tags: php, mysql

I have this idea that has been bugging me. In the ordinary way of fetching rows, I would use this PDO code:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=odesk', 'root', '123456');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from foo");
$sth->execute();

while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $bar = $result['bar'];

    echo $bar . '   ' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

and get the rows one after the other. The PHP script I use to fetch the rows is residing on the server side and I only the client side I have only a browser.

Is there a method I can use to advance the internal row pointer after every page refresh such that a client sees a new record every time a page refresh is done?

My auto-incremented column is of no help since it has been badly edited and some rows removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(it's not mysqli code, it's pdo)

`"select * from foo limit 2,1";`

gets you row 3

`"select * from foo limit 3,1";`

gets you row 4

`"select * from foo limit 4,1";`

gets you row 5

So, if you can pass to the next page the next number on the list, that's what it will get you from your db.  There are several ways to do this, sessions etc, or use a url string (GET)

```
yourpage.php?next=7
```

all you have to do is increment the next page

```
'select * from foo limit ' . (int)$_GET['next'] . ',1';
```

This is not an entire tested solution, think of it more as pseudo code, just to show how it could be done.

(int) is used to typecast the incoming variable to an integer and is just a poormans way of protecting your db from sql injection attacks, in real life of course you'd use, Mysql or PDO prepared statements, 'course you would!

Comment: The limit method is simply ingenious,but my little journey  into the inner workings of mysql shocked me.